# counting no of times each word is repeated using haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

iam new to Haskell and functional programing...

i want to pass in the function as a string and count no of times each syntax such as (if,else, elseif for, while, dowhile) is exist in the function using haskell.

example if give an input like this

```
if(i=0){  for(i=0;i<num;i++){if(name== name)}
}elseif (i=3){for(i=3;i<num;i++){}}
else{while (i>3){name = name; i--;}}
```

i expect the output.(it has to give no of times each syntax appear)

```
[(if,2),(for,2),(elseif,1),(else,1),(while,1)]
```

i had done the coding. as shown below

```
import Control.Arrow

syntaxCount :: String -> [(String, Int)]
syntaxCount = map (head &&& length) . group .sort  . words
```

this function works but it displays the result like this.

```
[("(i=3){for(i=3;i<num;i++){}}",1),("(i>3){name",1),("=",1),("else{while",1),("for(i=0;i<num;i++){if(name==",1),("i--;}}",1),("if(i=0){",1),("name)}",1),("name;",1),("}elseif",1)]
```

can anyone help me to get rid of all the unwanted stuff and get the result like this..

```
[(if,2),(for,12),(elseif,1),(else,1),(while,1)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd split this into a function that produces a list of the keywords in the input string, and a function that counts distinct elements of a list

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Arrow

keywords :: String -> [String]
keywords = words . map (\x -> if isAlpha x then x else ' ')

count :: Ord k => [k] -> [(k,Int)]
count = map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

Then you can define `syntaxCount` as a simple composition

```
syntaxCount = count . keywords
```

For example

```
>> let inp = "if(i=0){  for(i=0;i<num;i++){if(name== name)}\n}elseif (i=3){for(i=3;i<num;i++){}}\nelse{while (i>3){name = name; i--;}}"
>> syntaxCount inp
[("else",1),("elseif",1),("for",2),("i",10),("if",2),("name",4),("num",2),("while",1)]
```

If you want to include just a specific set of keywords, then you should filter explicitly for them

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

allKeywords :: Set.Set String
allKeywords = Set.fromList ["if", "else", "elseif", "for", "while"]

keywords = filter (`Set.member` allKeywords) . words . map removePunc
  where removePunc c = if isAlpha c then c else ' '
```

Comment: thank you. Chris.. and can you please explain me what this **import qualified Data.Map as Map** does..

Comment: @Sathyabaman I actually removed that line for simplicity. But it imports the module `Data.Map`, but imports it *qualified*, so that you have to explicitly declare that you're using function from that module by writing `Data.Map.` before them. By writing `import qualified Data.Map as Map` I gave it the short name `Map` so that I can use function from it as `Map.insert` rather than `Data.Map.insert`.

Comment: `keywords` can be `Data.Text.split (not isAlpha)`

Comment: @misterbee You'd actually need `keywords = filter (not . Text.null) . Text.split (not . isAlpha)` to filter out empty strings.

Comment: agreed. was on mobile, didn't get a complete/correct tested answer out before. Just wanted to point out `Data.Text.split`